# Hide Columns VBA Code - Type Mismatch Error

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, type-mismatch

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Range("$D:D")
        Case "Disposal": ACF_Disposal
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```

I am attempting to hide **Columns; G, H, O, S, T and U** when the Dependant Dropdown choice of "*Disposal*" is selected in **Column D**.
I am completely new to VBA here. This code was taken from online and worked with 1x Cell selection; I.E The Macro executes when **Cell D3** is populated with "Disposed" and *only* **Cell D3**.

Have attempted to amend range to; "*D:D, $D, $D;D$ and $D3:$D1000* the same error code each time; *Run-time error '13': Type mismatch*

I do now know enough about VBA syntax to correct this and appreciate any help.

Edit;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.CountLarge > 1 Exit Sub Then
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Value
 Case "Disposal": ACF_Disposal
 End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell in Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D"))`, `Select Case cell.Value`... `Next`.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand how to implement this, imagine I am a toddler. 
Last used code in Pascal 25 years ago.

Comment: If you're changing a drop-down (one-cell only), then I'd add `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Exit Sub` before `If Not....`, then change `Select Case Range("D:D")` to `Select Case Target.Value`.

Comment: Thank you. Still receiving Compile error, syntax error.

Comment: My bad, forgot the `Then`, should be `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Spot on. Thank you. Appreciate the help and the patience